# Time for create TestProbe in Akka TestKit

Tags: akka, akka-testkit

I have trait for override actorOf in tests:

```
trait ActorRefFactory {
  this: Actor =>

  def actorOf(props: Props) = context.actorOf(props)
}
```

And I have worker actor, which stop self when receive any message:

```
class WorkerActor extends Actor {
  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case _ => { context.stop(self) }
  }
}
```

Also I have master actor, who creates actors and hold them in queue:

```
class MasterActor extends Actor with ActorRefFactory {
  var workers = Set.empty[ActorRef]

  override val supervisorStrategy = SupervisorStrategy.stoppingStrategy

  def createWorker() = {
    val worker = context watch actorOf(Props(classOf[WorkerActor]))
    workers += worker
    worker
  }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case m: String =>
      createWorker()
    case Terminated(ref) =>
      workers -= ref
      createWorker()
  }
}
```

And this test, which is failed:

```
class ActorTest(val _system: ActorSystem) extends akka.testkit.TestKit(_system)
  with ImplicitSender
  with Matchers
  with FlatSpecLike {

  def this() = this(ActorSystem("test"))

  def fixture = new {
    val master = TestActorRef(new MasterActor() {
      override def actorOf(props: Props) = TestProbe().ref
    })
  }

  it should "NOT FAILED" in {
    val f = fixture

    f.master ! "create"
    f.master ! "create"

    f.master.underlyingActor.workers.size shouldBe 2

    val worker = f.master.underlyingActor.workers.head
    system.stop(worker)
    Thread.sleep(100)

    f.master.underlyingActor.workers.size shouldBe 2
  }

}
```

After Thread.sleep in the test, I give error by "1 was not equal to 2". I have not idea what happening. But, if guess I can assume that TestProbe() can't create in the time. What can I do?

Comment: If I send to worker PoisonPill instead system.stop(worker), it works. But I do not know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically boils down to an asynchronicity issue that you want to try and avoid in unit tests for Akka.  You are correctly using a `TestActorRef` to get hooked into the `CallingThreadDispatcher` for the `master` actor.  But when you call `system.stop(worker)`, the `system` still us using the default async dispatcher which will introduce this race condition on the stopping and then re-creating of a worker.  The simplest way I can see to fix this issue consistently is to stop the worker like so:

```
master.underlyingActor.context.stop(worker)
```

Because you are using the `context` of `master` and that actor is using the `CallingThreadDispatcher` I believe this will remove the asnyc issue that you are seeing.  It worked for me when I tried it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. For example, if I add println statement in case Terminated, I got it. It means that Master actor received terminated message.

Comment: @Leonard, why are you re-asserting after the stop that the size should still be 2?  If the terminated is received properly then the size of the list should go from 2 to 1.  Your failure is telling you that your size is 1 and that does not match your expectation of 2 but your expectation should actually be 1.

Comment: it's not that simple. Look at createWorker() method. When worker has being terminated, master create new worker and put it in workers set.

Comment: @Leonard, I added another answer.  This one worked for me when I tried it.